# Understanding use of "this" in java

Tags: java, this

I'm trying to understand the `this` keyword in java.  I wanted to rewrite this code by using the `this` keyword instead.  Please let me know if I've done it right.  Here's the original code:

```
public class Book {

    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String publisher;

    public Book(String bookTitle, String authorName, String publisherName){
        title = bookTitle;
        author = authorName;
        publisher = publisherName;
    } 
}
```

And here's the re-written code:

```
public class Book {

    private String title; 
    private String author; 
    private String publisher; 

    public Book(String title, String author, String publisher){
        this.title = title; 
        this.author = author; 
        this.publisher = publisher; 
    }
}
```

Have I done it correctly?

Thanks,

Kevin

EDIT:  Thanks for the responses...  one more question:  in the constructor of the revised code, which side of the equals sign refers to the class variables?  For example, in `this.title = title;`, does `this.title` refer to the `title` variable from the constructor or from the class variable?

Based on the responses below, I think the answer is `this.title` refers to the class variable `title`.

Comment: You have done it correctly.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand about the this keyword?  Yes, you have it correctly there.

Comment: Yes you have done it correctly. Personally I feel the use of this makes the code less understandable. I'd rather prefer the first approach than the 2nd as I feel the code to be more readable and easily understandable...

Comment: its correct and this will represent the instance variables of the class

Comment: You have done it. this has "sence" to use if you have variables with same names in same class for example in your case, variable as parameter title can be distinguished from variable in your class with this. If you won't write this `title = title` has no sence.

Comment: Thanks for the responses... the question arose because I'm reading the book "Teach Yourself Java in 21 Days," and one of the examples uses the this keyword.  There's a small section on it, but I still wasn't clear after I read it.  I've been looking for clarification online and I just wanted to make sure I understood it.  Thanks again.

Comment: @All Some IDEs can introduce getters and setters, constructors from the fields, and automatically add `this`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The `this` keyword means "the instance of this class that I'm running inside right now". You usually don't need it for variable or method references, but in this (common) case where the constructor parameters have the same name as the fields they're being saved in, using `this` distinguishes to the compiler between the fields and the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You've used `this` correctly.

Now, to understand why `this` works this way notice that the local variable (*constructor* parameter) names in your previous version of the *constructor* are different than your *class* member names. Hence, `this` wasn't required since there wasn't any ambiguity.

In the second version, since, their names are the same the *constructor* parameters over shadow or hide the class member fields within the *constructor* body. Hence, `this` which points to the current object instance is required to refer to them explicitly.

Also note that `this` **cannot** be used from a *static* context (*block* or a *static method*) for the obvious reason that no current object instance is associated with it. It must be used from inside a *constructor*, *instance block* or an *instance method*.

Answer (score 1):

From [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

> The most common reason for using the this keyword is because a field
>   is shadowed by a method or constructor parameter.

Lets take an example which illustrates what above statement means. I have added comments at appropriate section of code for your reference.

```
public class ThisKeywordExample {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void setVar(int x, int y) {
        x = x;  // Setting private variable x value 
        y = y;  // Setting private variable y value
        System.out.println(x + " " + y); // prints 10 20 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThisKeywordExample obj1 = new ThisKeywordExample();
        obj1.setVar(10, 20);
        System.out.println(obj1.x + " " + obj1.y); //prints 0 0 because the effect is limited to the local copies of x &  y in the setVar method
    }
}
```

Now I would suggest you change `setVar` method to

```
public void setVar(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;  // Setting private variable x value 
            this.y = y;  // Setting private variable y value
            System.out.println(x + " " + y); // prints 10 20 
        }
```

and see how it works now.

Answer (score 0):

"this" allows you to easily distinguish between variables of the same name within a class/object.

It appears to me that you have used "this" correctly.

I would, however, caution from using the same variable names for multiple uses. In this situation, it is acceptable; however it would be wise to avoid getting into bad programming habits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have understood `this` *in java* correctly. From Sun's original documentation:

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 0):

look in your Question there are two big concepts of using this has evolved.
In the 1ST and foremost case this is used to refer to the current object which has evolved that constructor means this carry a referenceid of current object....
In the 2nd case this is used primarly to distinguish between the local parameters and instance variables because the name of both variables types are same....and it is a rule in java that local variable overshadow the instance variables(of same name) when used in any local block or method...so here this differentiates between the instance variable(this.title) and local variable(title)..
And remember this lets u refer directly to the object you can use it to avoid any name space collisions that may ocuur between instance and local variables...