# what does return this do in this code?

Tags: java

In this code

```
class Parent {

    void show() {
        System.out.print("parent");
    }

    Parent a() {
        return this;
    }

}

class Child extends Parent {

    void show() {
        System.out.print("child");
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Parent a = new Child();
        Parent b = a.a();
        b.show();
    }
}
```

What does `return this;` do? `b.show()` is invoking the child method show. So does `this` return reference to its child class? If not then how is the `show()` method of child being called?

Comment: That's not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Not sure of the downvotes, this is actually not a bad question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325512/understanding-use-of-this-in-java?rq=1 - pasted the wrong thing before, stupid windows clipboard

Comment: @JarrodRoberson That still isn't necessarily a duplicate. This is asking why dogs bark. The question you link is asking why dogs eat. Sure they're both about dogs, but not duplicates.

Comment: Random tip of the day - Classes should start with a capital letter `child` --> `Child`.

Comment: @Takendarkk One step ahead of you.

Comment: I didn't mean you should edit the OP's code. Now you give the impression that they really know what they are doing when in fact they do not.

Comment: And what makes them not know what they're doing? It's improving the quality of the post. The question itself is good, but the code might be a little shabby. Why shame posters?

Comment: You didn't teach the man to fish, you gave it to him. This is _"what makes them not know what they're doing?"_

Comment: You posted your comment; had you not, I would have. Normally I don't edit code but he 1) wasn't having a problem, and 2) given the code, the problem wouldn't have been with the casing of the types anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, all non private and non static methods in Java are virtual, which means that you will always execute the method of the type of the object reference.

In this case, you have

```
parent a=new child();
```

which means the client (the class/method) using `a` can only execute the methods defined in `parent` class but the behavior is defined by type `child`.

After this, when you execute:

```
parent b=a.a();
```

`a.a()` will return `this`, but `a` is a `child` and `this` is the current object reference, which is `a`. Value of `b` is `a`.

Then you execute

```
b.show();
```

Which is invoking `child#show`, so the program will output "child".